# SSIS Variables as expressions to generate Start and end dates of a quarter with input year and month passed as variable

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2016, ssis-expressions

Can someone help me create SSIS expressions for variables to generate QuarterStart(DateTime) and QuarterEnd(DateTime) as a variable with year(int32) and quarter(int32) passed on as user variables.

The equivalent T-SQL script would be

```
    @FISCAL_YEAR INT = 2023,
    @QUATER INT = 1
SELECT 
    DATEFROMPARTS(@fiscal_year,(@Quater * 3)-2,1) AS QuaterStart,
    EOMONTH(DATEFROMPARTS(@fiscal_year,@Quater * 3,1)) AS QuaterEnd
```

Answer (score 0):

My easy way to store the values by executing a sql task for populating a SSIS variable.

1. Create two SSIS variables with datetime as data type QUATER_START_DATE and QUATER_END_DATE
2. Create an `Execute SQL Task`
3. Add the script already in the question in to this task.

   ```
   declare   @FISCAL_YEAR INT = 2023,
   @QUATER INT = 1
   SELECT 
   DATEFROMPARTS(@fiscal_year,(@Quater * 3)-2,1) AS QuaterStart,
   EOMONTH(DATEFROMPARTS(@fiscal_year,@Quater * 3,1)) AS QuaterEnd
   ```
4. Change the `Result set` property to `Single`
5. Click `Add` in the `Result Set section` of `Execute SQL Task`
6. Set the `Result Name` as `column name` of the sql command and map it to the respective `SSIS variables`.

Once this task is executed it will populated with the values returned by the sql statement.